# client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe while running kafka on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I am trying to start kafka on EC2.
So I connect to EC2, start zookeeper, then server, producer and consumer. Everything works fine, but after about 10 minutes the server stops working and returns the error ***client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe***, which causes producer and consumer to return ***Broker may not be available***. What could be the reason for this or is there a default timeout?

And the other issue is related to it. When I try to redeploy and connect once again via terminal to EC2 via ssh, I am unable to do so, because I get an ssh error: ***connect to host ec2-55-194-25-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out.***
And the only thing that helps me is to shut down ec2 and restart.

Comment: Sounds like a general EC2 / networking issue, not Kafka related. Have you tried contacting AWS Support for this? What about setting up MSK / Confluent Cloud instead of installing Kafka on your own VMs?